# lwuit Resource limit exceeded for TCP client sockets

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, midp

I use lwuit and browser about 20 pages, 
and then i got execption:

java.io.IOException: Resource limit exceeded for TCP client sockets
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.open0(), bci=0
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.connect(), bci=142
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.open(), bci=133
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.openPrim(), bci=4
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.createConnection(), bci=13
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.connect(), bci=43
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.streamConnect(), bci=109
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.startRequest(), bci=9
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(), bci=35
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(), bci=3
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.getHeaderField(), bci=5
 - com.sun.lwuit.browser.HttpRequestHandler.resourceRequested(HttpRequestHandler.java:138)
 - com.sun.lwuit.html.HTMLComponent$2.run(HTMLComponent.java:817)
HttpRequestHandler->IOException: Resource limit exceeded for TCP client sockets
Error connecting to stream

anyone can tell me how to fix it?

Comment: if you paste here code about your TCP connection it will be easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

You should probably `close` the TCP sockets after using them. Otherwise they stay around in an open state, and if the operating system allows only 20 connections to be open at a time, you will get this exception.

Comment: but how? how to close the tcp socket connection in htmlcomponent code: